# Java RSA private key generation when public key is known

Tags: java, rsa, key-generator

Is there a way to **generate a RSA private key** in java, when the **public key is known**, say 3 ?

I can't find a way to do this with Class KeyPairGenerator, from java.security package...

my question is very simple, I'm not looking for info related to cryptography.
Just want to know, if **I have the public exponent** for **RSA**, is there a way **in java** to **get the private exponent**, for that public exponent, for a given modulus length , e.g. 2048?
This should shed some light on the topic:
https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/RSA_(cryptosystem)#Key_generation
https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/65,537

Comment: what code have you tried so far ? why is it not working ? what have you searched for (libs ?)?

Comment: An RSA public key consist and an exponent *and* a modulus.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Sort answer is "no".

Long answer is to use [sunrsasign](https://github.com/frohoff/jdk8u-dev-jdk/blob/master/src/share/classes/sun/security/rsa/RSAKeyPairGenerator.java) Provider, which implements RSAKeyPairGenerator such that the public exponent is 65537:
*"/**
 * RSA keypair generation. Standard algorithm, minimum key length 512 bit.
 * We generate two random primes until we find two where phi is relative
 * prime to the public exponent. Default exponent is 65537. It has only bit 0
 * and bit 4 set, which makes it particularly efficient.
**/*

if you want **a different public exponent** you need to **create your own provider** and integrate it with JCA.

more on the math behind this [here](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/16901/modular-exponentation-for-rsa-why-is-216-1-commonly-chosen?fbclid=IwAR0BzZx_a-DN_UYVQEt9gKRjWumrdAIIxuUEE24y9btTV85esci4WZEzj0M).

Answer (score 4):

The whole point of [public-key cryptography](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Public-key_cryptography) is that the private key remains secret. If there would be a way to easily generate a private key from a public key the encryption schema would be broken.

Yes, you can probably brute-force the private key but it won't be easy:

> The strength of a public key cryptography system relies on the computational effort (work factor in cryptography) required to find the private key from its paired public key. Effective security only requires keeping the private key private; the public key can be openly distributed without compromising security.